# Keyframe animation appearing from the center

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am creating a keyframe transition sequence. I am wanting the circle to appear for two seconds and then the star to appear for the other two seconds. I am running into a couple of issues.

1. Why is my star turning into a rectangle at the end of the animation?
2. How can I get the star to appear from the center rather than the top-left corner sliding in diagonally?
3. Why does my red circle disappear for a second or two and then the star appear?

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1 forwards;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1 forwards;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0%, 49% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
    shape-padding: 10px;
    /*transition: all 1s ease; */
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
  }
  /* Standard syntax */
  @keyframes example {
    0%, 49% {
      background-color: red;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    50%,
    100% {
      shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
      shape-padding: 10px;
      /* transition: all 1s ease; */
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="star">
</div>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x2sjdcbq/) acceptable? Basically the change from no `clip-path` to the `clip-path` at 50% seems to be causing the 2nd and 3rd problems.

Comment: @Harry Yes, that is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my star turning into a rectangle at the end of the animation?

That's because what probably is a typo error in the below line. You have set `forwards` to the iteration count property and so the `animation-fill-mode` takes its default value (which is `none`). This makes the `div.star` to snap back to its original shape (the one before start of the animation, a square) once the animation has completed. Removing the `forwards` from the below line and setting it to the correct property will solve this issue.

```
animation-iteration-count: 1 forwards;
```

---

> How can I get the star to appear from the center rather than the top-left corner sliding in diagonally?

Well, getting the star to appear from center (as though its growing) is going to be almost impossible. I will explain the why part a bit later but why the star looks like it is sliding in diagonally is rather simple to explain. The element's initial dimension is 250x250, once the animation starts it is 50x50 and stays that way till `49%` of the animation. At `50%` no height or width is specified and so the element starts to grow gradually from 50x50 to its original size, which is. 250x250 (this growth will complete at 100%). Since the element has `margin: 0 auto`, it is always center aligned with respect to the container and so when it grows to its full size, it looks like the top-center point (50%, 0%) point is fixed and element expands towards right, left and bottom. Now this coupled with the `clip-path` produces the diagonal movement effect.

**Snippet showing how the element grows without clip-path:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: justify;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes example {
  0%, 49% {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  50%,
  100% {}
}
```

```html
<div class="star">
</div>
```

**Snippet showing the clip-paths effect at 5 stages during the growth:**

Below snippet would make the reason for the slide more clear as you can see how the shape looks at 5 stages during the growth (from 50x50 to 250x250)

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  color: white;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
}
.dim-50 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.dim-100 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.dim-150 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.dim-200 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.dim-250 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="star dim-50">
</div>
<div class="star dim-100">
</div>
<div class="star dim-150">
</div>
<div class="star dim-200">
</div>
<div class="star dim-250">
</div>
```

---

> Why does my red circle disappear for a second or two and then the star appear?

This is partly because of the `clip-path` and a lack of `height` and `width` setting within `50%, 100%` keyframe. Since the element is only gradually growing from 50x50 to 250x250 (and it reaches its full size only by the end), the `clip-path` that you've designed based on original size (250x250) in mind actually starts working only at around `68.75%` mark. This is because of the pixel values used in the `clip-path`. For example, the first point is 125,0 but the element's width is only 50px at `49%` and so its width becomes 125px only at `68.75%` (200px increase in `50%` duration would mean `18.75%` time for 75px increase assuming a linear timing function, for ease it'd be a bit longer but you get the point). Because of this, from the 50% mark approximately till the 68.75% mark you get to see nothing.

Another reason for the disappearance can also be attributed to the lack of a `clip-path` setting in the `0%, 49%` keyframes. Because of this, the clip-path of the element is slowly animated from no clip at the start to the actual clip-path at 50% mark.

---

**Solutions:**

There are two solutions and they are as follows:

- Use your original approach, add `height: 250px`, `width: 250px` and `border-radius: 0%` to the `50%, 100%` keyframes. Set a dummy clip-path on the element at `0%, 49%` keyframes.

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  .star {
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: justify;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  @keyframes example {
    0%, 49% {
      background-color: red;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50px 0, 50px 50px, 0 50px, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
    }
    50%,
    100% {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      border-radius: 0%;
      shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
      shape-padding: 10px;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0px, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="star">
  </div>
  ```
- Set the element's `height` and `width` as 250px at the start of the animation itself, use a circular `clip-path` with 25px radius to produce the circle. This way we can avoid the need for a dummy clip-path. I prefer this approach just because it needs no dummy clip-path.

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  .star {
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: justify;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  @keyframes example {
    0%, 49% {
      background-color: red;
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(25px at center);
    }
    50%,
    100% {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
      shape-padding: 10px;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="star">
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Awesome thank you and GREAT answer! I have a question pertaining to the `-webkit-clip-path`. I changed my star to an image and removed the `-webkit-clip-path` because I liked how your snippet grew into the shape and that is what I am after. Why does my star appear before the circle even starts going away?? https://jsfiddle.net/ouknt5pa/

Comment: Can I have different `animation-name:`'s in my code or would I need different animations to create new animations. Regarding my last post. I want the circle to transform into the star, not the outer div's square shape from the circle.

Comment: Gradually transforming the circle into star will be almost impossible with CSS because then we would need to create the circle also with polygon clip path which is impossible. I think it can be done with SVG but I cannot provide a sample for that now. I will see in the morning.

Comment: Am I able to gradually transform it with the image? But why does the image show up on the circle before the image should even appear?

Comment: @Paul: I think you hadn't seen one of my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800877/keyframe-animation-appearing-from-the-center/35801721#comment59275449_35801721) which had the reason for image appearing on the circle. By *gradually transforming is impossible* what I meant is transforming a circle shape into a star shape gradually is impossible. What you are currently doing is transforming a circle into a square (which is possible) with a star as background image. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ouknt5pa/2/) is another example of a more gradual change.

Comment: Gotcha, so no image background. Is that all you did? Seems to work much better now.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thank you for all the help!