# CSS Keyframe image appearing before it should

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am having a tough time figuring out why my image within my keyframe (of the star) is showing up before the 50% keyframe. Right now it is showing up almost immediately.

What can I do to make it show up when I am wanting it to (after 50%)?

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star-container {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}
.star {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-animation-name: star;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes star {
  0%, 21% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  22%,
  45% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  49% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    /*shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );
  shape-padding: 10px;
  /*transition: all 1s ease; */
    /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );*/
    background-image: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/star.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  /* Standard syntax */
  @keyframes star {
    0%, 21% {
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    22%,
    45% {
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 90%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    49% {
      background-color: red;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    50%,
    100% {
      /*shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );
  shape-padding: 10px;
  /*transition: all 1s ease; */
      /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );*/
      background-image: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/star.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="star-container">
  <div class="star">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reason:

As I had mentioned in my reply to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800877/keyframe-animation-appearing-from-the-center/35801721#comment59288917_35801721), the problem is because there is no background image specified in any of the frames before the `50%` keyframe. This means that the UA treats it like a gradual change of background image from `0%` to `50%`. But since there cannot be a intermediate state for image display, it appears at roughly half duration between `0%` to `50%` for an animation with linear timing function (for other timing functions like ease, ease-in, ease-out it would be a little before or after the mid way point but the logic is the same).

**Demo as proof of above point:**

In the below snippet, I have set the `animation-timing-function` to `linear` and have inserted frames to change the `background-color` to `yellow` at `25%` mark. You'd see how the image now appears at the exact same time when the color changes to yellow. This is to prove the statement in first para.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star-container {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}
.star {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-animation-name: star;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes star {
  0%, 21% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  22% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  45% {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  49% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    /*shape-inside: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );
  shape-padding: 10px;
  /*transition: all 1s ease; */
    /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(125px 0, 175px 85px, 250px 90px, 190px 160px, 225px 250px, 125px 210px, 25px 250px, 60px 160px, 0px 90px, 75px 85px );*/
    background-image: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/star.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="star-container">
  <div class="star">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution:

The fix to this problem is to set `background-image` to `none` in all the frames before the `50%` mark.

**Demo:** (Have removed all the vendor-prefixed versions to keep the snippet small)

```css
body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.star-container {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}
.star {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: justify;
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes star {
  0%, 21% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: none;
  }
  22%, 45% {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: none;
  }
  49% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: none;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    background-image: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/star.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="star-container">
  <div class="star">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again! Keep up the great answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-timing-function: linear` to `.star` this will show the image exactly after 2s.

Comment: But why is it showing before 50% in the duration I have? I am not wanting this to be 10 seconds long.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question, I have edited my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: That kind of helps, but the image still loads before the time that it should.